# Training, testing, and validation sets for bidirectional LSTM (BLSTM)

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, keras, recurrent-neural-network

When it comes to normal ANNs, or any of the standard machine learning techniques, I understand what the training, testing, and validation sets should be (both conceptually, and the rule-of-thumb ratios). However, for a bidirectional LSTM (BLSTM) net, how to split the data is confusing me.

I am trying to improve prediction on individual subject data that consists of monitored health values. In the simplest case, for each subject, there is one long time series of values (>20k values), and contiguous parts of that time series are labeled from a set of categories, depending on the current health of the subject. For a BLSTM, the net is trained on all of the data going forwards and backwards simultaneously. The problem then is, how does one split a time series for one subject?

- I can't just take the last 2,000 values (for example), because they might all fall into a single category.
- And I can't chop the time series up randomly, because then both the learning and testing phases would be made of disjointed chunks.

Finally, each of the subjects (as far as I can tell) has slightly different (but similar) characteristics. So, maybe, since I have thousands of subjects, do I train on some, test on some, and validate on others? However, since there are inter-subject differences, how would I set up the tests if I was only considering one subject to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has more to do with your particular dataset than Bi-LSTMs in general.

You're confusing splitting a dataset for training/testing vs. splitting a sequence in a particular sample. It seems like you have many different subjects, which constitute a different sample. For a standard training/testing split, you would split your dataset between subjects, as you suggested in the last paragraph.

For any sort of RNN application, you do NOT split along your temporal sequence; you input your entire sequence as a single sample to your Bi-LSTM. So the question really becomes whether such a model is well-suited to your problem, which has multiple labels at specific points in the sequence. You can use a sequence-to-sequence variant of the LSTM model to predict which label each time point in the sequence belongs to, but again you would NOT be splitting the sequence into multiple parts.